# Lock builtin laptop keyboard but keep an external USB keyboard functioning

Tags: keyboard, lock, peripherals

I have a laptop but also an external USB keyboard connected to it. Is it somehow possible to lock the built-in laptop keyboard (i.e. keys pressed should have no effect) but keep the external one responsive?

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. My laptop is Lenovo ThinkPad T420.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible, with the use of `xinput`.

To start, run `xinput list` in a terminal. You should see something similar to the following:

```
zachary@MCServer:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Now, you'll probably see two keyboards, instead of just one, since you have two keyboards plugged in. I recommend unplugging the USB keyboard and running the command.

Take note of the ID of `Virtual core XTEST keyboard`. In my case, it's `5`.

Plug in the USB keyboard, since you're about to disable the internal one.

Run this command:

```
xinput set-prop 5 "Device Enabled" 0
```

and replace 5 with your device ID.

To re-enable the keyboard:

```
xinput set-prop 5 "Device Enabled" 1`
```

replace 5 with your device ID.

You can also put these in separate scripts if you want, and run those from the terminal (or create `.desktop` files to the scripts you make).

**Edit:**
If you want, I've made a script that will check the state of the specified device in `xinput` and toggle it (to on if off, to off if on). You will need to change the `device` variable to the corresponding ID.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

device=5 #Change this to reflect your device's ID

output=$(xinput list-props $device | awk '/Device Enabled/{print $4}')

if [ $output == 1 ]
  then
    xinput set-prop $device "Device Enabled" 0
elif [ $output == 0 ]
  then
    xinput set-prop $device "Device Enabled" 1
else
  echo "Something's up."
fi
```

**Edit 2:**
Improved script - automatic device ID detection (provided its name is fixed) and desktop notifications.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# name of the device - we hope this will not change
DEVNAME="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
# here we find the device ID corresponding to the name
device=$(xinput list | grep "${DEVNAME}" | sed "s/.*${DEVNAME}.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/g")
# here we get the enabled state
state=$(xinput list-props $device | awk '/Device Enabled/{print $4}')

if [ ${state} == 1 ]; then
    # if it is enabled, disable it and show a notification
    xinput set-prop ${device} 'Device Enabled' 0
    notify-send -u normal "Keyboard lock" "Keyboard \"${DEVNAME}\" (id=${device}) was disabled."
elif [ ${state} == 0 ]; then
    # if it is disabled, enable it and show a notification
    xinput set-prop ${device} 'Device Enabled' 1
    notify-send -u normal "Keyboard lock" "Keyboard \"${DEVNAME}\" (id=${device}) was enabled."
else
    # some weird state - do nothing and show critical notification
    notify-send -u critical "Keyboard lock" "Keyboard \"${DEVNAME}\" (id=${device}) is neither enabled nor disabled. State is \"${state}\""
fi
```

Comment: Great! Seems it's working. One more question - can the device ID change between boots or is it guaranteed to be always the same for my particular configuration?

Comment: It should stay the same. It'll probably change if you reinstall, but just a reboot shouldn't affect it. Would you mind accepting this answer, since it worked?

Comment: Oh, it seems like they might reset on reboot.  This is beyond my knowledge for a script to adapt, but I may be able to get someone to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755967/how-to-make-a-program-that-finds-ids-of-xinput-devices-and-sets-xinput-some-set/18756948#18756948

Comment: I'll accept it once I get my laptop back home and play with it a little bit more, don't worry ;-). Regarding the changing ID, I have a strong feeling that the name ("AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" in my case) won't change so I could ``sed`` the id out of it. Ugly, but I'm not controlling a nuclear power plant so no big deal :).

Comment: Oh good. At least you know what you're doing with scripts. I had to learn to write conditionals and variables in bash for that script :p.